# How to do a count and select variables in Sparql

Tags: sparql

Is there a way to select variables and get a count of the total variables in one Sparql query ? I want to return ?s and get a count of all the ?s matches

I tried variations of the query below but I keep getting errors

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) as ?cnt) ?s { ?s a <http://foo.org/test>  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) as ?cnt) (sample(?s) as ?sample)
{ ?s a <http://foo.org/test>  }
```

`COUNT` means the query is an aggregate query so there are many `?s`.  `SAMPLE` picks one - which one is not defined.

If you want all the `?s` and the `COUNT`, you'd normally count in your application - to do in the query is a bit odd, you need to ask twice:

```
SELECT ?cnt ?s 
{ { SELECT (COUNT(*) as ?cnt) { ?x a <http://foo.org/test> } }
   UNION { ?s a <http://foo.org/test> }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andy ! I should note that using UNION is a slow way of doing it (orders of magnitude). Using a join is much faster

Comment: There is no join in any of the examples.  In my seconds illustration. the results are much larger.